# Не запускается проект GWT в Intellij Idea

Tags: java, gwt

При запуске пишет ошибку:

> Error running 'Unnamed (1)': GWT SDK path is not specified correctly
>   in GWT Facet settings for module

Пытался добавить gwt через конфигурацию 'add framework support', но там не было gwt. Подскажите как исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сталкивался с такой же проблемой - нашел решение, но уже немного подзабыл. Насколько помню:

Первым делом я на всякий случай создал шаблонный gwt maven проект из архетипа mojo:
 mvn archetype:generate

-DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo \

-DarchetypeArtifactId=gwt-maven-plugin \

-DarchetypeVersion=2.8.1

Все библиотеки подгрузились

Затем устранение самой ошибки - в проекте с ошибкой заходим в структуру проекта (обычно справа сверху значок папки с тремя синими квадратиками). Там слева в списке Project Settings выбираем Facets. в GWT Facet надо указать Target Web Facet и ниже (насколько помню) выбрать (из списка выпадающего) путь к модулю GWT.

После создания шаблонного maven-gwt я просто сравнивал эти настройки со своим и нашел в чем разница.

Answer (score 0):

Добавление фреймворка, это лишь обозначение, что проект/модуль проекта является каким-то проектным типом. Если GWT, как фреймворк уже добавлен (это делается раз где-то в начале создания проекта/модуля проекта, создали, добавили один-другой фреймворк). Вообще, чтобы добавлять GW фреймворк в плагинах должна быть включена поддержка GWT.

Но это все не относится к ошибке. Если проект не под maven/gradle, где зависимости от GWT библиотек прописываются в соответствующих настройка сред сборок. Если проект без них, то GWT SDK, то есть все библиотеки нужно ручками скачать, куда-то положить, а затем их добавить/указать путь к файлам в Facet настройки в свойствах проекта.